# How to split content after a space

Tags: php

I'm just a newbie in PHP ,

now I have a trouble with the split content function,
I have a string look like this :

```
$tring = 'World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of landing tough group rise';
```

my splitcontent code :

```
 if(strlen($string)<$width){
        return $string;
    }
    $string = substr($string,0,$width);
    $string = $string.'...';
    return $string;
```

the result is :

World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of lan....  ,

when i insert

```
$string = substr($string,0,strrpos($string,' '));
```

it look like this :

World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of... ,

Now I want to my string look like this :

World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of landing...
What will I do ? Thanks for any helping

Comment: That result seems inconsistent with the (implicit) instructions.  Sounds like you want to limit the string to no more than $width length, right?  And landing spelled out would surpass $width.  So the second one is correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english , i not quite understand what you saying :( , my purpose is split content after a space look like this "... chances of landing...." . But when i used  
$string = substr($string,0,strrpos($string,' '));
it split the string before a space looke like this "... chances of..."

Comment: It seems that you need to split the content if the content length is greater than the width. Is that right ? and you don't want words to be cut in middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this function will help you. It will help you to truncate content or string without letting words to cut in the middle. It also considers HTML tags.

```
function truncate_content( $text, $length = 100, $ending = '...', $exact = false, $considerHtml = true) 
{
    if ($considerHtml) 
    {
        // if the plain text is shorter than the maximum length, return the whole text
        if (strlen(preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $text)) <= $length) 
        {
            return $text;
        }

        // splits all html-tags to scanable lines
        preg_match_all('/(<.+?>)?([^<>]*)/s', $text, $lines, PREG_SET_ORDER);
        $total_length = strlen($ending);
        $open_tags = array();
        $truncate = '';

        foreach ($lines as $line_matchings) 
        {
            // if there is any html-tag in this line, handle it and add it (uncounted) to the output
            if (!empty($line_matchings[1])) 
            {
                // if it's an "empty element" with or without xhtml-conform closing slash
                if (preg_match('/^<(\s*.+?\/\s*|\s*(img|br|input|hr|area|base|basefont|col|frame|isindex|link|meta|param)(\s.+?)?)>$/is', $line_matchings[1])) 
                {
                    // do nothing
                    // if tag is a closing tag
                } 
                else if (preg_match('/^<\s*\/([^\s]+?)\s*>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) 
                {
                    // delete tag from $open_tags list
                    $pos = array_search($tag_matchings[1], $open_tags);
                    if ($pos !== false) 
                    {
                        unset($open_tags[$pos]);
                    }
                    // if tag is an opening tag
                } 
                else if (preg_match('/^<\s*([^\s>!]+).*?>$/s', $line_matchings[1], $tag_matchings)) 
                {
                    // add tag to the beginning of $open_tags list
                    array_unshift($open_tags, strtolower($tag_matchings[1]));
                }
                // add html-tag to $truncate'd text
                $truncate .= $line_matchings[1];
            }

            // calculate the length of the plain text part of the line; handle entities as one character
            $content_length = strlen(preg_replace('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', ' ', $line_matchings[2]));
            if ($total_length+$content_length> $length) 
            {
                // the number of characters which are left
                $left = $length - $total_length;
                $entities_length = 0;
                // search for html entities
                if (preg_match_all('/&[0-9a-z]{2,8};|&#[0-9]{1,7};|[0-9a-f]{1,6};/i', $line_matchings[2], $entities, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
                    // calculate the real length of all entities in the legal range
                    foreach ($entities[0] as $entity) 
                    {
                        if ($entity[1]+1-$entities_length <= $left) 
                        {
                            $left--;
                            $entities_length += strlen($entity[0]);
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            // no more characters left
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                $truncate .= substr($line_matchings[2], 0, $left+$entities_length);
                // maximum lenght is reached, so get off the loop
                break;
            } 
            else 
            {
                $truncate .= $line_matchings[2];
                $total_length += $content_length;
            }
            // if the maximum length is reached, get off the loop
            if($total_length>= $length) {
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        if (strlen($text) <= $length) 
        {
            return $text;
        } 
        else 
        {
            $truncate = substr($text, 0, $length - strlen($ending));
        }
    }

    // if the words shouldn't be cut in the middle...
    if (!$exact) 
    {
        // ...search the last occurance of a space...
        $spacepos = strrpos($truncate, ' ');
        if (isset($spacepos)) 
        {
            // ...and cut the text in this position
            $truncate = substr($truncate, 0, $spacepos);
        }
    }

    // add the defined ending to the text
    $truncate .= $ending;
    if($considerHtml) 
    {
        // close all unclosed html-tags
        foreach ($open_tags as $tag) 
        {
            $truncate .= '</' . $tag . '>';
        }
    }


return $truncate;

}
```

In this

`$text` is the content or string.

`$length` is the length you want to cut the string with

`$ending` is the ending sequence to be added if the content is cut.

`$exact` specifies whether you need to cut the string exactly without taking in to account the word. If you specifeis `$exact` to be true, then it will not consider the word.

`$considerHtml` parameter ask you whether we need to consider html preventing breaking html tags when splitting content.

So in your case you can just use :

```
$string  =  "World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of landing tough group rise";
echo truncate_content($string, $width);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks you , Sabari . That's awesome :D . Sorry , i don't have enough reputation to vote for your answer :D

Comment: @user3064132 Its Ok. Mark solved if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 3):

This will split the content at `$width` chars but if it lands on a word, it will match to the end of the word (so it will really be $width+[num chars till end of word if in middle of word]. A "word" being defined as letters, numbers, underscore, hyphen or single quote. This will account for stuff like "England" or "England's" or "pre-text" as a whole word.

```
$width = 20;
$text = "World Cup 2014 draw: England's chances of landi-ng tough group rise";
preg_match("~^.{".($width-1)."}([\w'-]+)?~i",$text,$m);
$newtext = $m[0].'...';
echo $newtext.'<br/>';
```

Comment: @user3064132 your welcome! if this works for you then please upvote/mark solved ;)

Comment: i on't have enough reputation to upvote :( , i just can check your answer . Thanks again :D